# C program compilation from a java program

Tags: java, c, compilation

I am trying to compile a c program from a java program on Linux platform. My snippet is.

```
          ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/gcc",
          "-c","/hipad/UserProject/example.c");

          Process proc = processBuilder.start();
```

There is no error during compilation of java program  but I am not able to get .o file. I tried to find out solutions but no one is working. 
Any suggestion.....

Comment: Does it work fine when you compile the c program manually with the same options ?

Comment: the .o file probably appears in the current working directory, whatever that is.

Comment: I can see that you are using a *nix machine right? I've noticed that providing the entire file path for files in that will help with most situations.....

Comment: Why do you want to do that? >_>

Comment: @Staven What's it matter? I can think of many reasons ... perhaps the OP is developing a C IDE in Java.

Comment: Thanks to all for quick reply...

Comment: @hyde- You are right sir, I could not notice that .o file was created on the current directory(eclipse). Thanks alot.

Comment: @DEV Cool. I'll write that as an answer a bit later, With some more details, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default working directory of a child process is what ever directory the Java process has as a working directory, which usually is where it was launched from. And by default *gcc* writes output files to current working directory. That's where you should find `example.o`.

There are two simple ways to solve this. You can give *gcc* `-o` option and full path and name of desired output file, or you can set working directory of child process, like this:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder =
    new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/gcc", "-c","example.c"); // source in working dir
processBuilder.directory(new File ("/hipad/UserProject")); // or whatever
Process proc = processBuilder.start();
```

See [ProcessBuilder javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for more info.