# Compiling a C program from Java or C# using MinGW

Tags: java, c#, mingw

I am building an app that would compile C programs and display the results on a Windows Platform.

The standard C compiler for Windows is MinGW.

Is there any API for MinGW in Java or C# and how do I call the compiler?

I have referred these links: [Calling C compiler from java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627788/calling-c-compiler-from-java-program) and [C program compilation from a java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463523/c-program-compilation-from-a-java-program).

Comment: Unclear what you are looking for outside of what shown in [C program compilation from JAva](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463523/c-program-compilation-from-a-java-program) link you've provided... Can you clarify what you expect to find except "start a Process" APIs in Java/C#?

Comment: If I have to compile my program then I need to install mingw but without installing just with the api call can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

MinGW has not an *API* by itself if what you are thinking about is a library. The only viable approach is to launch the compiler as a process. The links you have referred explain how to, just follow them.

Comment: Please see the comment in the question.

Comment: Do you want to compile a C program with MinGW from java without installing MinGW? If so I would say it is impossible.

Comment: Are there any other apis?

Answer (score 0):

There is no C/C++ compiler on Windows and unlikely to have cross-compiler installed by default on *nux platforms - so bring you own.

And there is no "API" that magically compiles C code either.

Note that both Java and C#/.Net have compiler services for its own languages - you may want to think about using C# instead of C. And as long as you have .Net Framework on Windows you get csc.exe compiler if you need to compile from command line.